# Magento 2 Remove Tier Price using Plugin

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, frontend, tierprice

```
How to remove tier price using plugin ?
```

I have no idea how to remove this price :(

Comment: you want to just hide the tier price from the product view page?

Comment: Yes but using with plugin only.